# How to get list of Sites and lists from Sharepoint using Web Services?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I want to get list of Sites and Lists from Sharepoint using Web Services.

Worked on  GetSite() and GetSiteAndWeb() functions of SiteData web service

Also tried Site and Lists.

I am unable to get list of sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `Webs.GetWebCollection` method from the Webs Web Service.

[Webs.GetWebCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getwebcollection.aspx)

When working through the SharePoint API, the terminology is different than when working in SharePoint itself.

Site Collection (SharePoint) -> Site (SharePoint API)
Site (SharePoint) -> Web (SharePoint API)